# Question about tempo/text markup in Lilypond

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I have the following score typeset in Lilypond:
[image: Music score with markup problems]
and I have two question about markup:

- I typeset "ritenuto" (slow down) as `\tempo "rit."`. Is it correct?
- How can I move `\tempo "Non rubato"` to the right so that there is more space for the box with "A"?

UPDATE:

- solution proposed by `@Lazy` and `@Elements in Space` below is to modify `X-offset` property for `MetronomeMark`:
- `\once \override Score.MetronomeMark.X-offset = #2`
- use markup where it is possible to add horizontal space with `\hspace`:

```
\tempo \markup { \hspace #2 "Non rubato" } 4. = 80-85
```

where in both cases `#2` denotes the amount of shift to the right.

Comment: As an aside, your note divisions and rest divisions don't really conform to the usual conventions for 3/4 and 6/8 time.  In particular, in the last three bars your repeated rhythm should be written with a dotted quarter note tied to a quarter note, not a half tied to an eighth.  This shows the player where the "beat" is in the middle of the tied note and helps them keep time.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you're right, thank you! I did not think about it as I just copy-pasted it from the 3/4 part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: *ritenuto* is not *slow down*, but *hold back*, so a slower tempo. *Slowing down gradually* would be *ritardando* or *rallentando*.

Marking the tempo change as Metronome Mark is correct. These marks are MetronomeMark grobs, usually created at the Score level. So you can shift these by doing something like

```
\override Score.MetronomeMark.X-offset = #2
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I somehow thought that it is _ritenuto_ for slowing down; did not heard about _ritardando_ before.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use `\once` for this particular issue.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov Although "Rit." can be used for both *ritenuto* and *ritardando*, I prefer "riten." for the former, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace yes, agree

Comment: @Aaron somehow, I memorized rit. = ritenuto. As I do not know Italian, I thought it means "decelerate" :-)

Comment: @Aaron Yes. But _ritenuto_ is significantly less common then _ritardando_, and while _rit._could theoretically possible it would make little sense to do so. People will just assume you mean _ritardando_.